# Best way to handle a derived class with a method not shared by any other derived class without adding it to the base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, derived-class

I am currently refactoring some code and am dealing with reorganizing a collection of about a dozen classes with some common methods into a set of derived classes with the shared code in the base, which implements an interface exposing the methods. So far the new structure is fairly straightforward and can be summarised as follows:

```
public interface IContract 
{
    public bool MethodA();
}
```

```
public abstract class BaseClass : IContract 
{
    // Default implementation
    public virtual bool MethodA() { return true; }
}
```

```
public class DerivedClassA : BaseClass 
{
    private readonly SomeServiceA service;

    // Class-specific implementation (if required)
    public override bool MethodA() { return service.CheckA(); }
}
```

Problem is that there is one derived class that contains a public method shared by no other derived class:

```
public class DerivedClassB : BaseClass 
{
    private readonly SomeServiceB service;

    public override bool MethodA() { return service.CheckB(); }
    public void MethodB() { service.PerformAnotherAction(); }
}
```

This method is currently invoked elsewhere in the codebase as below:

```
// Factory initialises a class of a type specified in config settings
IContract instance = ClassFactory.GetInstance();

bool ClientMethodA()
{
    return instance.MethodA();
}

void ClientMethodB()
{
    if (instance.GetType() == typeof(DerivedClassB))
    {
        ((DerivedClassB)instance).MethodB();
    }
}
```

I'd rather the invoking code not know anything about DerivedClassB but I'm not sure how to avoid the casting. My question is whether this design structure is the most optimal given this workflow, and if not, how could it be improved while adhering to SOLID principles?

Comment: Can you rewrite your `DerviedBaseClassB`as `public override bool MethodA() { var result =  service.CheckB(); service.PerformAnotherAction(); return result; }`?

Comment: @SomeBody I'm not sure that calling `service.PerformAnotherAction();` in `MethodA` is intended. There would be no need to have a `public` method for that case.

Comment: @SomeBody unfortunately not, sorry. I wrote out the invocation in simplified form for brevity, in the actual code the two methods are not called sequentially and cannot be combined. I will amend the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Casting is okay but you're using reflection to determine the type. A solution might be a _friendly_ cast like: `if (instance is DerivedClassB instanceB) { instanceB.MethodB(); }`. Maybe you can simplify that to `(instance as DerivedClassB)?.MethodB();`. If more than one class will have such a `MethodB` then introducing an interface like `ISupportMethodB` might help.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann thanks for that advice, sadly I'm a bit shackled to C# 5 for this project so I'd have to weigh up the prospect of upgrading the language just for this change against the possible disruptions.

Comment: A solution in C# 5 might be: `var typed = instance as DerivedClassB; if (typed != null) typed.MethodB();` The new language featues will do more or less the same.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann thanks, I might try that to at least eliminate the reliance on reflection. Cheers!